# VM201:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at HTMLDialogElement.<anonymous> (dialog.js:43:36)

Tags: javascript

Al ejecutar las lineas que muestro abajo, recibo el mensaje de error del título, el problema es que no veo que falte información aquí abajo. El error lo marca en el archivo dialog.js, pero en otros casos si funciona, sin hacerle modificaciones. Necesito entender donde falla y por que.

```js
function imgPopUpIIBB_onClick()
{
    var retval = window.showModalDialog('Controles/PopUpImpuestos.aspx?Impuesto=IIBB&DetallesImpuesto=&IdProveedor=1124433&ImporteFactura=1000&Operacion=edit&CreditoAsocFac=0&DetallesImpuestoAnt=', '', 'center:yes;dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:350px;resizable:no;status:no;help:no;scroll:yes;');
    if (retval != undefined)
    {
        if (retval == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('ctl00_cMain_UCTree1_UCHead1_hDetallesIIBB').value = null;
            document.getElementById('ctl00_cMain_UCTree1_UCHead1_txtIIBB1').value = 0;
            document.getElementById('ctl00_cMain_UCTree1_UCHead1_hPorcIIBB').value = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(retval);
            document.getElementById('ctl00_cMain_UCTree1_UCHead1_hDetallesIIBB').value = retval.split('@')[0];
            document.getElementById('ctl00_cMain_UCTree1_UCHead1_txtIIBB1').value = retval.split('@')[1];
            document.getElementById('ctl00_cMain_UCTree1_UCHead1_hPorcIIBB').value = retval.split('@')[2];
            changeIIBB();
        }
    }
} 

imgPopUpIIBB_onClick();
```

El error que recibo es:
**VM201:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at HTMLDialogElement. (dialog.js:43:36)**

Por las dudas el código de dialog:

```js
var aCtrlCalendar = null; // Esta variable es necesaria para que la reconozca en la devoluci�n del calendario

(
    function () {

        if (!window.showModalDialog) {
            window.showModalDialog = function(url, arg, opt) {
                url = url || ''; //URL of a dialog
                arg = arg || null; //arguments to a dialog
                opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //options: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles
                var caller = showModalDialog.caller.toString();
                var dialog = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
                dialog.setAttribute('style', opt.replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
                dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 5px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body" src="' + url + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
                document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
                document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    dialog.close();
                });
                dialog.showModal();
                //if using yield or async/await
                if(caller.indexOf('yield') >= 0 || caller.indexOf('await') >= 0) {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        dialog.addEventListener('close', function() {
                            var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                            document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                            resolve(returnValue);
                        });
                    });
                }
                //if using eval
                var isNext = false;
                var nextStmts = caller.split('\n').filter(function(stmt) {
                    if(isNext || stmt.indexOf('showModalDialog(') >= 0)
                        return isNext = true;
                    return false;
                });
                dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
                    var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                    document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                    if (returnValue) {
                        nextStmts[0] = nextStmts[0].replace(/(window\.)?showModalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(returnValue));
                        eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));
                    }
            
                });
                // throw 'Execution stopped until showModalDialog is closed';
                throw 'ShowModal';
            };
        }
    }
)();
```

Cuando hago clic para ver la linea donde falla en el código anterior me marca en:

eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));

Ese código no lo desarrollé yo, pero se me complica comprender donde está precisamente la falla.